# Register same object multiple times with different configuration

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have this api client `ICommunicationClient(url, tenant)` registered in my IoC container. Now I'm facing the scenario where I can have **1 to n** api clients. I need to register all of them and I'm not sure how to handle that. I've seen there's this `RegisterCollection` in SI though.

I'm considering use a `ICommunicationClientProvider` as a wrapper around the actual clients. It contains a list with all the registered clients and methods to retrieve them. I feel this is not the best approach and of course, it "forces" me to touch other pieces of the app.

```
public class CommunicationClientProvider : ICommunicationClientProvider
{
    public CommunicationClientCollection CommunicationClientsCollection { get; set; }
    public string Tenant { get; set; }

    public ICommunicationClient GetClients()
    {
        return CommunicationClientsCollection[Tenant];
    }
    public void SetClients(CommunicationClientCollection clients)
    {
        CommunicationClientsCollection = clients;
    }
}

public interface ICommunicationClientProvider
{
    ICommunicationClient GetClients();
    void SetClients(CommunicationClientCollection clients);
}
```

This to host the collection

```
public class CommunicationClientCollection : Dictionary<string, ICommunicationClient>
{
}
```

Here I register the collection against SI

```
        var clients = new CommunicationClientProvider();
        foreach (var supportedTenant in supportedTenants)
        {
            clients.CommunicationClientsCollection
                .Add(supportedTenant, new CommunicationClient(
                    new Uri(configuration.AppSettings["communication_api." + supportedTenant]),
                    new TenantClientConfiguration(supportedTenant)));
        }
        container.RegisterSingleton<ICommunicationClientProvider>(clients);
```

Do you know a better way of doing this? This is a normal scenario for example when you have multiple databases.

***UPDATE:*** - *ITenantContext part* -
This is basically how my tenant context interface looks like:

```
public interface ITenantContext
{
    string Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

and this is where I'm making my call to communication api:

```
public class MoveRequestedHandler : IHandlerAsync<MoveRequested>
{
    private readonly IJctConfigurationService _communicationClient;
    private readonly ITenantContext _tenantContext;

    public MoveRequestedHandler(IJctConfigurationService communicationClient, ITenantContext tenantContext)
    {
        _communicationClient = communicationClient;
        _tenantContext = tenantContext;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(MoveRequested message)
    {
        _tenantContext.Tenant = message.Tenant;
        _communicationClient.ChangeApn(message.Imei, true);

        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

here I register the ITenantContext

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ITenantContext, TenantContext>();
```

The tenant is defined within the `MoveRequested` object (`message.Tenant`). 
How can I make CommunicationClient aware of that tenant?

Comment: Your question is currently too vague. Please show some code with your question.

Comment: I've updated the potential solution, let me know if more detail is required please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If adding an `ICommunicationClientProvider` abstraction causes you to make sweeping changes throughout your application, there is clearly something wrong. You should typically be able to add features and make changes without having to do sweeping changes. And as a matter of fact, I think your current design already allows this.

Your `ICommunicationClientProvider`) acts like a factory, and [factories are hardly ever the right solution](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100). Instead, your are much better of using the [Composite design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). For instance:

```
sealed class TenantCommunicationClientComposite : ICommunicationClient
{
    private readonly ITenantContext tenantContext;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ICommunicationClient> clients;

    public TenantCommunicationClientComposite(ITenantContext tenantContext,
        Dictionary<string, ICommunicationClient> clients) {
        this.tenantContext = tenantContext;
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    object ICommunicationClient.ClientMethod(object parameter) =>
        this.clients[this.tenantContext.CurrentTenantName].ClientMethod(parameter);
}
```

You can register this class as follows:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ICommunicationClient>();
foreach (var supportedTenant in supportedTenants) {
    dictionary.Add(supportedTenant, new CommunicationClient(
        new Uri(configuration.AppSettings["communication_api." + supportedTenant]),
        new TenantClientConfiguration(supportedTenant)));
}

container.RegisterSingleton<ICommunicationClient>(
    new TenantCommunicationClientComposite(
        new AspNetTenantContext(),
        dictionary));
```

Here the `ITenantContext` is an abstraction that allows you to get the current tenant on who's behalf the current request is running. The `AspNetTenantContext` is an implementation that allows you to retrieve the current tenant in an ASP.NET application. You probably already have some code to detect the current tenant; you might need to move that code to such `AspNetTenantContext` class.

Comment: ICommunicationClient is a bunch of interfaces, not sure how to get done the last bit in your sealed class. 
This is a console app so no ASP.Net stuff in. 
By adding :ICommunicationClient I'll end up "implementing" all methods from the interface :S

Comment: @Rober: In your console app, you'll have a different `ITenentContext` implementation. If your `ICommunicationClient` has many members, you are violating the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). You should fix that and that will solve the problem with the ugly composite as well.

Comment: Thanks @Steven still not entirely sure where to populate the ITenantContext but I'll get it working. I got the composite stuff done

Comment: @Rober If you update your question with the code you currently have that determines which tenant is currently running, I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: But in your old model, how do you decide which communication client to call? How do you determine the tenant?

Comment: In the old model there was only one tenant and one communication client. Now, all depends on the message.Tenant property

Comment: But you are running a console application? Does the console application run for multiple tenants *at the same time*? Or just for one tenant (supplied by a command line argument perhaps?).

Comment: Yes. Yes. 
Console app, tenant=all. Message driven. Subscribed to multiple single tenant queues.

Comment: I updated with my last changes but still failing when it tries to get the object from the Dictionary, any idea? I added the interface registration in the IoC module as well.

Comment: @Robert okay,  that's interesting. What is this MoveRequested message and why does it contain the Tenant name? I expect this Tenant to be contextual information, which should not be part of the message itself but rather part of context/header/envelope. Can you explain why you think it belongs on the message?

Comment: because of my app is listening to other single tenant queues (es, it, ca, ...), when a MoveRequested message is received I identify the tenant through that property. This way I know which communication client I need to use